# IMPORTDATA shows empty output

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a `IMPORTDATA` that has been working well. A week ago it started to show "empty output". I tried changing the formula but so far no luck.

[Formula + url here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZW_qBk23lUtQBnX9H5Yr3ueO7SXZ3baqTe96Y1kf2rc/edit?usp=sharing)

I expect the result to extract [tags](http://prntscr.com/ofp81t) from [the url](https://www.etsy.com/listing/590795846/svg-dxf-png-pj-masks-squadgoals-catboy?ref=user_profile&bes=1).

I've tried `IMPORTXML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this:

```
=IMPORTXML(A2, "//span[@class='text-largest strong override-listing-price']")
```

[image]

---

```
=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(A2, "//a[contains(@class,'btn btn-secondary')]"))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `IMPORTXML` function rather than `IMPORTDATA`. I've added a tab to your sheet.